# jQuery triggering custom event is causing unknown runtime error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using below code to bind a custom event to an element.

```
  jQueryelement.bind("custom",{}, function(){});
```

and i am trying to `trigger` this with

```
   jQueryelement.trigger("custom");
```

This is working fine in Firefox. But causing unknown runtime error in IE. Please help me in this. TIA
I'm using jQuery v1.5.2

Comment: Use this jQueryelement.on("custom",{}, funtion);

Comment: Which version of Jquery and IE ? This seems to work with me for JQ 1.9.0 and IE 9.

Comment: what exactly is 'funtion' ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `bind()` and `trigger()` in jQuery 1.5.2 seems to work fine. My guess is there is some other code in your app which is causing this.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JUx4a/) - works in FF, Chrome, IE9, IE8/IE7 combatibility mode and IE quirks mode

---

Demo uses this code:

```
$('body').bind('custom', {}, function(){
    alert("Well, Hello!")
});

$('body').trigger('custom');
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness as of JQuery 1.7 (I know this question relates to JQuery 1.5.2) you are better to use `on()`. If you are using it as an event for the whole page use something like:

```
$(document).on("custom", function() {
  alert("Triggered!");
});

$.event.trigger("custom");
```

or if you are triggering on an element:

```
$(".myElement").on("custom", function() {
  alert("Triggered!");
});

$(".myElement").trigger("custom");
```